# SQLite without any install or run permissions

Tags: excel, vba, sqlite

I have a need to run a small, low use but multi user database and would like to use SQLite for this.  However, the desktop environment is heavily restricted by group policy.  I can download the SQLite files but all exe files run on white list only, so I cannot run the command line.

My plan was to store data in SQLite and use Excel as a front end.  Is there any way I can use VBA and Excel to create the SQLite database and tables or am I up Schitz Creek with no paddle?

Access is a no go as the licencing costs for the amount of users would be prohibitive.

Comment: This would probably require an ODBC driver, which you would not be allowed to install.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Confirmed what I suspected.